# No puedo añadir Google App Engine a Atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, mongoatlas

Levante una aplicacion con Node, Express y Mongoose a App Engine que tiene unas APIs que guardan datos en una DB que tengo en Atlas. Tuve problemas para lograr la conexion con la DB hasta que habilite todas las IPs para conectarse, lo cual me indico que tenia que añadir la IP de App Engine al whitelist.
El problema es que ya cree un Acceso VPC sin servidores, con red, subred, router y conector y estoy recibiendo este error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: Operation is not allowed. The "vpcaccess.connectors.use" permission is required.
```

Lei que la solucion era añadir unos permisos o borrar vpc_access_connector de app.yaml. Ya añadí los permisos y borrar el vpc_access_connector no es una opcion ya que entiendo que es la forma de lograr una IP estática para añadirla a la whitelist.

Estoy perdido, apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar Google Cloud y AWS es aún más dificil, ya no sé que más intentar. Cómo puedo corregir el error? Hay alguna otra forma de conseguir la IP de App Engine?